# how to open Iphone's database(created) in Android?

Tags: android

Database is created in Iphone using SQLite.Now I want to use same database file in Android and insert the data into tables.How to do that?

Android Developer

Comment: do you want to include the database while programming for the application ?

Comment: Yes,At the time of programming only iam going to include the database file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to copy the file in your applications folder say assets folder and copy the database from the local file, first time the app is loading.

[this](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) link will give you a solution.

Comment: If i do like dat also it is giving error : Unable to open database file